# how to create a c++ dynamic library using project class?

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a c++ project with many classes and sub-directory. I want to convert my communication code subdirectory to share library(dynamic library). But I have little experience with C++ and cmake. I don't know how to do. I share my test code tree and cmakelist.txt

```
.
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── main.cpp
└── sim_haberlesme
    ├── hab_ortak
    │   ├── haberlesmeAraKatman.cpp
    │   └── haberlesmeAraKatman.h
    ├── paketleyici2.cpp
    ├── paketleyici2.h
    ├── paketleyici.cpp
    ├── paketleyici.h
    └── protobuf
        ├── protobuf_deserialize.cpp
        ├── protobuf_deserialize.h
        ├── protobuh_serialize.cpp
        └── protobuh_serialize.h
```

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(CmakeTest)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

add_executable(CmakeTest main.cpp sim_haberlesme/paketleyici2.cpp sim_haberlesme/paketleyici2.h sim_haberlesme/paketleyici.cpp sim_haberlesme/paketleyici.h sim_haberlesme/protobuf/protobuh_serialize.cpp sim_haberlesme/protobuf/protobuh_serialize.h sim_haberlesme/protobuf/protobuf_deserialize.cpp sim_haberlesme/protobuf/protobuf_deserialize.h sim_haberlesme/hab_ortak/haberlesmeAraKatman.cpp sim_haberlesme/hab_ortak/haberlesmeAraKatman.h)
```

(If you want me to share the code, I'll share)
I want to create dynamic lib with using sim_haberlesme directory. But this directory have too many classes and subdirectory. In this reason i don't know how to start and how to edit cmakelist file.
Can you tell me how to start convert .cpp file to .so file and how to edit cmakelist.txt file?
By the way you can share tutorials

Comment: Why don't you show us your CMakeLists file?

Answer (score 0):

Something like that in your CMakeLists:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(CmakeTest)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

add_library(sim_haberlesme SHARED)
target_sources(sim_haberlesme PRIVATE
hab_ortak/haberlesmeAraKatman.cpp
hab_ortak/haberlesmeAraKatman.h
paketleyici2.cpp
paketleyici2.h
paketleyici.cpp
paketleyici.h
protobuf/protobuf_deserialize.cpp
protobuf/protobuf_deserialize.h
protobuf/protobuh_serialize.cpp
protobuf/protobuh_serialize.h
)

add_executable(test)
target_sources(test PRIVATE main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(test PRIVATE sim_haberlesme)
```

Comment: Can you edit my cmakelist.txt? I shared my cmakelist.txt

Comment: I edited mine. It should be complete. Tell me if it works.

Comment: You have called ADD_LIBRARY for library sim_haberlesme without any source files. 
``` CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:27 (add_executable):
  add_executable called with incorrect number of arguments


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:28 (target_sources):
  Cannot specify sources for target "test" which is not built by this
  project.
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:29 (target_link_libraries):
  Cannot specify link libraries for target "test" which is not built by this
  project.

Comment: Update your CMake tool to a more recent version (at least 3.11 for sources to be optional in the add_executable() call)

Comment: otherwise use `add_library(sim_haberlesme SHARED "")`

Comment: I tried add add_library(sim_haberlesme SHARED        hab_ortak/haberlesmeAraKatman.cpp ...) but I got this error 
`CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:38 (add_executable):
  add_executable called with incorrect number of arguments


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:39 (target_sources):
  Cannot specify sources for target "test" which is not built by this
  project.


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:40 (target_link_libraries):
  Cannot specify link libraries for target "test" which is not built by this
  project.
`

Comment: Same issue with add_executable(). The source files argument became optional since 3.11. EIther update your cmake tool or put main.cpp in `add_executable(test main.cpp)`

Comment: And try checking [the doc](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_executable.html) by yourself when the error as explicit as this one.